# Determine a basis in given subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $V$ be the subspace of $R^4$ consisting of the vectors $ x = (x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4)^T$
whose coordinates satisfy the equation $ x_4 = x_1 + 2x_2 − 3x_3$ . Determine a basis in $ V$
containing the vector  $  v = (1, 1, 1, 0)^T$

I figured it out by myself that we can find 1 other vector in this subspace(Let's say $ w= (0,1,0,2 ) $). So $ w $ and $ v $ can be basis of dimension $2$. However the answer is $ \dim=3 $ . What did I do wrong?

Comment: How can we know before you tell us how you deduced that $\dim V=2$?

Comment: I have edited to question.Thanks for suggestion

Comment: Your argument is not wrong, it is incomplete.. can you show that any vector in $V$ is a linear combination of $v$ and $w$ (In your notation)? if not, and this is the case, there is at least one vector which cannot be written as $av+bw$ for any $a,b\in \Bbb R$. Add such a vector to the basis and see what happens now by repeating the same reasoning.

Comment: @InsideOut so what is the way to find out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $V$ is the kernel of a linear map from $\Bbb R^4$ into $\Bbb R$. Since the range of that map is $\Bbb R$, it follows from the rank-nullity theorem that $\dim V=4-1=3$. So, no, it is not $2$. For instance a basis of $V$ is$$\left\{(1,1,1,0)^T,(0,1,0,2)^T,(0,0,1,-3)^T\right\}.$$

Comment: without the knowledge of Kernel. What is the other way to find out?

Comment: In general, a subspace of $\Bbb R^n$ defined by $k$ conditions is $n-k$. And it is never smaller than that.

Comment: what do you mean by k conditions?

Comment: In this case, you have a single condition, which is $x_1+2x_2-3x_3=x_4$.

Comment: Thank you very much.I accept your solution

Comment: I'm glad I could help.